# Selenium webdriver Assert click element worked

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bdd, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating a web page, and I am having lots of issues in clicking in a element, so I implemented this

```
try {
    element.click();
} catch (WebDriverException e) {
    clickJS(element);
}
```

clickJS is a method I wrote to click using javascript approach, it usually works, however I am having issues when the expression to click does not throw any exception, but in the future steps will fail because it did nothing. Is there a way for assert a click has 'worked' even though it did not throw any exception.
ps: Iam sure the webelement is clickable
PS: I am using chrome webdriver

Comment: Do you really need this condition? You just can do jsclick always.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to do a jsclick so you can actually test if the element isn't covered. I'd recommend to try and not use jsclick at all.

Comment: Does something on the page change when you click? If so you could check if the change has happened

Comment: 1. try different ways of clicking the element. in action chains, try with click, hover and click, double click options and find out the most consistent one. 2. Check which element you are finding? Is the element wrapped inside div/span tags and you are finding parent tag instead of child (may happen)? can you please share the relevant HTML code and the way you are identifying the element?

Comment: Have you tried using mouse actions to hover over the element/parent element to highlight it first. Can you provide some sample html of what the structure looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic way to determine if a click was successful because a click could do just about anything... navigate to another page, click a checkbox, dynamically load another part of the page, etc.

In general, I would say that this is not the right approach if you are trying to automate a customer scenario. For example, you attempt a click but didn't anticipate some dialog popping up. Your normal click would throw an exception that another element would receive the click but your JS click would succeed. You shouldn't want that click to succeed because a user couldn't click that element without dealing with the dialog first. This may cause a strange failure down the road that will be hard to trace. Do a "normal" click each time. As you run the script, you will find intermittent failures. Investigate them and find solutions, e.g. wait for some dialog to close because 1 in 10 times it closes slowly and so on. In the end, you will have a more robust suite.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your click is actually happened or not in some of the scenarios.
Ex: most of the case click will lead to some change in the UI that might be UI change,HTML source code change or some text might change.if nothing is changing after your click then the click itself is no use.

Solution: take a snap shot before ur click and take a snapshot after click then compare both images if u found any difference then ur click performed successfully else not.